# How to save user drawn layers into files(.shp or .tiff)?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I am developing a wpf gis application using arcgis runtime sdk. In my application user can define FeatureCollectionTable schema and draw features(such as polyline,polygon,point and etc) on map. Now, I need to save this user drawn feature layer as a file(.shp or .tiff). I searched on internet but I didn't found any solution.

Please help me if possible provide a snippet of code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to be able to store and restore the contents (rather than explicitly outputting as a Shapefile), you could use [`ToJson`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Data_FeatureCollection_ToJson.htm) to serialize the and [`FromJson`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/M_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Data_FeatureCollection_FromJson.htm) to reuse later. You could also save it to a Portal Item using any of the [`SaveAs`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Data_FeatureCollection.htm) functions.